# access c++ stl map only using iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I want to have a class with map variable as a private variable:

```
class CTest{
private:
 std::map<int, int> m_map;
public:
 std::map<int int>::iterator get_iterator();
 void add(int key, int val) { m_map[key] = val; }
}
```

Is there any way that in function `some_action()` i can only using `get_iterator()` iterate over the map for example:

```
CTest c;

/* here i want to go through that m_map, but i cannot have access to it */
void some_actoin(){
 ???
}

int main(void){
  c.add(1, 1);
  c.add(2, 3);
  some_action();
}
```

regards 
J.

Comment: You need some way of telling when to *end* iterating, not just a function to get an iterator. Other than that, just do as usual but use `get_iterator()` instead of e.g. `m_map.begin()`.

Comment: why can't you expose `m_map.begin()` and `m_map.end()`? You could of course create your own logic, like `get_iterator()` returns the current iterator (default `begin()`) and increments by one afterwards, if `end()` then start over, but that would hardly be intuitive to use

Answer (score 6):

If you really wanted to do this, you could add public methods to get the beginning and end iterators, e.g.

```
class CTest{
private:
    std::map<int, int> m_map;
public:
    std::map<int, int>::const_iterator cbegin() { return m_map.cbegin(); }
    std::map<int, int>::const_iterator cend() { return m_map.cend(); }
};

CTest c;

void some_action()
{
    for (std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = c.cbegin(); it != c.cend(); ++it)
    {
        // do action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a "beginning" and an "end" to iterate over it.

e.g.

```
class CTest{
private:
 std::map<int, int> m_map;
public:
 std::map<int int>::const_iterator cbegin();
 std::map<int int>::const_iterator cend();
 void add(int key, int val) { m_map[key] = val; }
}

void some_actoin()
{
 for(std::map<int int>::const_iterator it = c.cbegin(); it != c.cend(); ++it)
 {
     const auto& val = *it;
 }

 // C++11
 for(const auto& val : c)
 {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. You will need at least m_map.end() to end the loop.
However I'd suggest instead of `get_iterator()` add something like `for_each` to your class that will accept `std::function`, and apply it to all elements in a map using `std::for_each`. This way your acton doesn't need even to know that it iterates map, it just does it's job.